# Python GUI App is not functioning well, help me fix it?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Here's my code of a gui app using tkinter library, it creats tables and prints orders for each table and gives the ability to edit orders on every table. the goal of it to know what did each table order. but editing the orders doesn't seem to work at all, I need help fixing it.

```html
import tkinter as tk

class TableOrdersApp:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.tables = []
        self.table_list = tk.Listbox(master)
        self.table_list.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH)
        self.table_list.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", self.refresh_label)
        self.orders_label = tk.Label(master, text="", anchor=tk.W, justify=tk.LEFT, wraplength=400)
        self.orders_label.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
        self.button_frame = tk.Frame(master)
        self.button_frame.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)
        self.add_button = tk.Button(self.button_frame, text="Add Table", command=self.add_table)
        self.add_button.pack(side=tk.TOP)
        self.remove_button = tk.Button(self.button_frame, text="Remove Table", command=self.remove_table)
        self.remove_button.pack(side=tk.TOP)
        self.edit_button = tk.Button(self.button_frame, text="Edit Order", command=self.edit_order)
        self.edit_button.pack(side=tk.TOP)
        self.remove_order_button = tk.Button(self.button_frame, text="Remove Order", command=self.remove_order)
        self.remove_order_button.pack(side=tk.TOP)

    def add_table(self):
        self.tables.append([])
        self.table_list.insert(tk.END, "Table {}".format(len(self.tables)))

    def remove_table(self):
        index = self.table_list.curselection()[0]
        self.tables.pop(index)
        self.table_list.delete(index)

    def refresh_label(self, event=None):
        self.orders_label.config(text="\n".join(self.tables[self.table_list.curselection()[0]]))

    def edit_order(self):
        index = self.table_list.curselection()[0]
        orders = self.tables[index]
        if self.orders_label.select_present():
            start_index = self.orders_label.index(tk.SEL_FIRST)
            end_index = self.orders_label.index(tk.SEL_LAST)
            selected_text = self.orders_label.selection_get()
            num_newlines = selected_text.count("\n")
            order_index = start_index.split(".")[0] - 1 - num_newlines
            new_order = tk.simpledialog.askstring("Edit Order", "Enter the new order:")
            orders[order_index] = new_order
            self.refresh_label()

    def remove_order(self):
        index = self.table_list.curselection()[0]
        orders = self.tables[index]
        start_index = self.orders_label.index(tk.SEL_FIRST)
        end_index = self.orders_label.index(tk.SEL_LAST)
        num_newlines = self.orders_label.get(start_index, end_index).count("\n")
        order_index = start_index.split(".")[0] - 1 - num_newlines
        orders.pop(order_index)
        self.refresh_label()
   

# Create the main window
root = tk.Tk()

# Create an instance of the TableOrdersApp class
app = TableOrdersApp(root)

# Run the main loop of the app
root.mainloop()
```

I tried to make it print a label and make it editable using "edit order" button, but the button itself doesn't seem to work, and I want it to print "Empty" if the table has no orders how can i do that.

Answer (score 0):

Look in `edit_order` and `remove_order` function. Must easier to write less coding.
Here is code:

```
import tkinter as tk

class TableOrdersApp:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.tables = []
        self.table_list = tk.Listbox(master)
        self.table_list.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH)
        self.table_list.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", self.refresh_label)
        self.orders_label = tk.Label(master, text="", anchor=tk.W, justify=tk.LEFT, wraplength=400)
        self.orders_label.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
        self.button_frame = tk.Frame(master)
        self.button_frame.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)
        self.add_button = tk.Button(self.button_frame, text="Add Table", command=self.add_table)
        self.add_button.pack(side=tk.TOP)
        self.remove_button = tk.Button(self.button_frame, text="Remove Table", command=self.remove_table)
        self.remove_button.pack(side=tk.TOP)
        self.edit_button = tk.Button(self.button_frame, text="Edit Order", command=self.edit_order)
        self.edit_button.pack(side=tk.TOP)
        self.remove_order_button = tk.Button(self.button_frame, text="Remove Order", command=self.remove_order)
        self.remove_order_button.pack(side=tk.TOP)

    def add_table(self):
        self.tables.append([])
        self.table_list.insert(tk.END, "Table {}".format(len(self.tables)))

    def remove_table(self):
        index = self.table_list.curselection()[0]
        self.tables.pop(index)
        self.table_list.delete(index)

    def refresh_label(self, event=None):
        self.orders_label.config(text="\n".join(self.tables[self.table_list.curselection()[0]]))

    def edit_order(self):
        index = self.table_list.curselection()[0]
        orders = self.table_list.get(index)
        print(index)
        order = orders 
        self.orders_label.configure(text=order)
         
         
        #if self.orders_label.select_present():
            #start_index = self.orders_label.index(tk.SEL_FIRST)
            #end_index = self.orders_label.index(tk.SEL_LAST)
           #selected_text = self.orders_label.selection_get()
            #num_newlines = selected_text.count("\n")
            #order_index = start_index.split(".")[0] - 1 - num_newlines
            #new_order = tk.simpledialog.askstring("Edit Order", "Enter the new order:")
            #orders[order_index] = new_order
            #self.refresh_label()

    def remove_order(self):
        remove_orders = self.table_list.curselection()
        self.table_list.delete(remove_orders)
        self.orders_label.configure(text="")
        
       
        #index = self.table_list.curselection()[0]
        #orders = self.tables[index]
        #start_index = self.orders_label.index(tk.SEL_FIRST)
        #end_index = self.orders_label.index(tk.SEL_LAST)
        #num_newlines = self.orders_label.get(start_index, end_index).count("\n")
        #order_index = start_index.split(".")[0] - 1 - num_newlines
        #orders.pop(order_index)
        #self.refresh_label()
   

# Create the main window
root = tk.Tk()

# Create an instance of the TableOrdersApp class
app = TableOrdersApp(root)

# Run the main loop of the app
root.mainloop()
```

Result when executes:

[image]

Result when selected:

[image]

Result when removed order:

[image]